# Geb select element that contains something

Tags: java, testing, groovy, geb

How do I select the value of a form select field when it has random numbers in its name?

```
<select name="select_(random numbers)">
     <option value="1"></option>
</select>
```

I have tried:

```
formValidity {$("form").(contains('validity')) = "1 year"}
```

which fails.

Comment: Found the answer my self: formValidity { $("form").find("select", name: contains('validity')).value("1 year")}

Comment: May be answer it yourself and accept it so that question doesn't remain eternally open :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this:

`formValidity { $("form select[name*='validity']") }`

`formValidity.value("1 year")`

You were trying to use the Geb way.

[Geb Selecting Manual](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/all.html#the__function)

You can also use CSS and jquery selectors which I used above and also prefer.

[CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

[JQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)